# What kind of light bulb is this?

Tags: lighting, bulb, light-fixture

The only engraving on the bulb I can see says "NRJ8EE" but Google searching that brings up nothing.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Also, if we can't identify the bulb, is anyone able to tell if the fixture would be able to support an LED bulb with the same base?

Comment: Looks like a 100 Watt metal halide, sometimes referred to as HID lamps.  They are not interchangeable unless the transformer is bypassed or replaced.

Comment: Note that a metal halide bulb is comparable in efficiency to an LED (around 100 lumens / watt). So there isn't much electricity to be saved by switching, and you will be hard-pressed to find an LED capable of putting out the thousands of lumens that a metal halide bulb does.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks. Should someone post their comments as answers so I can mark it as correct? Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been stated High Intensity Discharge lamps only use a specific bulb and as the name implies, is energized under high voltage. Unless a new type of bulb is labeled for this type of lamp it would be wise to use an exact replacement bulb. I've noticed that LED lights have become increasingly more powerful (brighter) and inexpensive the past few years. If energy conservation (or frugality) is a priority it might be worth investigating if the present high energy using lamps should be replaced with the cooler emitting LED's. Here is a link you may find helpful, to one such lamp: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00DJPMD3K?keywords=security%20LED&qid=1443644066&ref_=sr_1_14&sr=8-14](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DJPMD3K)

Comment: here' another link to a HID LED: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B013GW8VLS?keywords=security%20LED&qid=1443644481&ref_=sr_1_41&sr=8-41